# When going through a for loop, if the variable is true it prints twice when it false it only prints once

Tags: python

I was making a checker for opinions on a website and when going trough it, if they both matched, the text would print twice and when it didn't match it would simply print once, I've been trying to figure out how to simply print the true matches and to only print them once.

The CMD output looks like this:
http://prntscr.com/h3ioli

```
import cfscrape, re, os, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



cc = open('cookie.txt').read()
mybbuser, sid = cc.split(':')
MainScrapper = cfscrape.create_scraper()


def substring_after(string, delim,back):
    return string.partition(delim)[back]


suspect = raw_input('User ID: ')

def reputationCheck(userid):
    reputationlist = []
    r = MainScrapper.get('https://v3rmillion.net/reputation.php?uid={}&show=positive'.format(userid), cookies={'mybbuser': mybbuser,'sid': sid})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    reputations = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("member\.php\?action=profile\&uid=(\d+)"))
    for reputation in reputations:
        reputationlist = reputationlist + [substring_after(reputation['href'],'uid=', 2)]
    if soup.find('span', {'class' : 'pages'}):
        pages = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'pages'}).text
        pages = substring_after(pages, '(', 2)
        pages = substring_after(pages, '):', 0)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

        for x in range(1, (int(pages))):
            r = MainScrapper.get('https://v3rmillion.net/reputation.php?uid={}'.format(userid) + '&show=positive&page={}'.format(x + 1), cookies={'mybbuser': mybbuser,'sid': sid})
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            reputations = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("member\.php\?action=profile\&uid=(\d+)"))
            for reputation in reputations:
                if not reputation == suspect:
                    reputationlist = reputationlist + [substring_after(reputation['href'],'uid=', 2)]

    for userids in reputationlist:
        if not str(userids) == str(suspect):
            victim = []
            r = MainScrapper.get('https://v3rmillion.net/reputation.php?uid={}'.format(userids) + '&show=positive', cookies={'mybbuser': mybbuser,'sid': sid})
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            reputations = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("member\.php\?action=profile\&uid=(\d+)"))
            for reputation in reputations:
                if substring_after(reputation['href'],'uid=', 2) == str(suspect):
                    print(str(userids) + 'exchanged reputation with ' + str(suspect))
                else:
                    pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for giving me a head's up on how to start-up!

Comment: How do I get more people to help me with my issue? I seem to be stuck @alfasin

Comment: Start by explaining *what* is the issue... second, you should create a *minimal* code example that reproduces the issue: don't make us go debug all your code.  You posted 50 lines of code, can you remove all the irrelevant parts and create a smaller example that reproduces the issue (e.g. without network calls, and without making me install new libraries in order to run it) ? If you want people to help you - you have to show some effort, right now it's just a code dump + "i have a problem" without any context...

Comment: As I already wrote, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider modifying your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not reputation == suspect:
if not str(userids) == str(suspect):
```

These should be:

```
if reputation != suspect:
if str(userids) != str(suspect):
```

Comment: John Kugelman, I appreciate the tip, although it results in the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should put your print function outside the loop.
Something like:

```
a=['x','y','z']
c=''
for b in a:
    c+=b
    print('this is inside loop, create multiple print: '+c)
print('this is outside loop, create single print, get it: '+c)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that.